# How to deal with non alpha numeric characters asp.net vb?

Tags: vb.net, csv, symbols, alphanumeric, non-alphanumeric

I am processing a lot of CSV files that have people data and occasionally names are used non-alpha numeric characters like á and those all become � symbols in the datatable. How do i prevent this problem ? I just wanna leave all the names as they are in the file without making any changes.

Thanks,

L

Comment: The most common reason for this is that it is actually encoded in ISO-8859-1 and interpreted as UTF-8. For less common reasons, the same principle applies.

Comment: Brilliant  & Thanks Esailija ... As you said, that was the reason .. Would you want to promote your comment as an answer ?

Comment: Only if it was helpful to you and resolved your issue :P

Comment: Your comment resolved my issue Esailija .. If you promote your comment as an answer, I will accept it, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common reason for this is that it is actually encoded in ISO-8859-1 and interpreted as UTF-8. For less common reasons, the same principle applies, that is, something is in different encoding that it claims to be.

Answer (score 0):

Change the character encoding in the database or decode it when you read from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

While processing, you need a Reader or something. I suggest you configure it by using a System.Encoding.UnicodeEncoding or UTF32Encoding.